# Subscriber should not stop on error in observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am struggling with a subscriber, which automatically unsubscribe itself on error:

```
observable
  .subscribe(
    (data) => {
      // some logic encountering an error during execution
      // comparable to throw new Error()
    }
  )
```

I can prevent it with using try / catch:

```
observable
  .subscribe(
    (data) => try { 
        // some logic encountering an error during execution
        // comparable to throw new Error()
      } catch(e) {
      }
  )
```

But it feels like a work around.

I have dived into the source of Subscriber and SafeSubscriber, which automatically call unsubscribe on error:

```
  private __tryOrUnsub(fn: Function, value?: any): void {
    try {
      fn.call(this._context, value);
    } catch (err) {
      this.unsubscribe();
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

Is the only way to prevent this behavior to implement an own Subscriber or using try / catch?

Comment: Use `retryWhen`

Comment: You're not providing important informations needed to give a good advice. Why do you want to throw an exception? Where do you plan to catch it?

Comment: It was only an example to show how an error could occur.

Comment: one major gotcha

Answer (score 3):

That's correct behavior. You can use the `catch()` operator to subscribe to the same source Observable again (or a different one on error).

```
source
  .catch(err => Observable.of(null))
  .subscribe(...);
```

This will just return `null` in the `next` handler instead of the original error.

Also note that any exception is rethrown if the subscriber doesn't have any `error` handler.

For example to just avoid throwing an error you could make:

```
source
  ...
  .subscribe(..., error => {});
```

However this will always unsubscribe the chain because this is one of the basic principles of Observables. They emit zero or more `next` notifications and one `complete` or `error` notification but never both.

It's hard to tell what problem are you trying to solve where you don't want to unsubscribe, sometimes you can use `Subject` and only pass it `next` notifications and ignore the rest...:

```
const subject = new Subject();
source.subscribe(val => subject.next(val));

subject.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: I want to handle errors in the subscriber gracefully without loosing the subscription.

Comment: @CSchulz That's not possible.