# Angular 4. Error in XHR request stops a chained observable

Tags: javascript, angular, error-handling, rxjs

I have an observable in Angular 4 that observes a input and when detect a url call a service thats launch a xhr request.

```
Observable.fromEvent(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'input')
  .debounceTime(500)
  .map((res: any) => { return res.target.value })
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .map((res: string) => String(res.match(this.regExpUrl)))
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .filter(res => res ? true : false)
  .switchMap(this.serviceThatReturnAObservableOfAXHRRequest))
  .subscribe(response => console.log(response), 
    err => console.log(err));
```

When the xhr return a 200 the observable of the inputs keep working and I can be able of write other url in the input, but when returns a error the observable of the input stops of working and if I write some in the input never pass throught the observable again.

Any idea why the error throwed by the request and catched in the subscribe could be breaking the observable of the input and when is a success no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct behavior. You can use for example `catch(() => Observable.of())` to just ignore the error or `catch(err => Observable.of(err))` to turn it into a `next` item or `retry()` to automatically re-subscribe to the source Observable.

Since you're using Angular the `http` service turns I think every non `2XX` into errors automatically.

Similar question:

- [Subscriber should not stop on error in observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44986873/subscriber-should-not-stop-on-error-in-observable/44987360#44987360)
- [Catch in Observable stops HTTP Calls from Observable.interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715543/catch-in-observable-stops-http-calls-from-observable-interval)

Comment: I use a catch to process the error and retry to re-suscribe and I've got the behavior expected. Thanks.